# Linking error due to `<<` overload inside class nested within templated class

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, friend

I am trying to overload the stream insertion operator `<<` to allow instances of my `gml::tensor<T>::shape` class to be printed to `stdout`.

I have reduced my code as much as possible in order to reproduce the source of the problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

namespace gml {
    template <typename T>
    concept Numeric = requires (T value) {
        T{1};
    };
    template <Numeric T>
    class tensor;
    template <Numeric T>
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const typename tensor<T>::shape&);
    template <Numeric T>
    class tensor {
    public:
        class shape {
        public:
            shape() = default;
            friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const shape&);
        };
        tensor() {
            std::cout << "tensor ctor" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    template <Numeric T>
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const typename tensor<T>::shape &s) {
        return out << "PRINTING AT LAST!!!\n" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    gml::tensor<long double>::shape s;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The linker error I get is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "gml::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, gml::tensor<long double>::shape const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test-eaec7e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am beginning to think that what I wish to do is not possible.

I could define the `<<` overload as a member function, but, before that, I'd like to know whether anything *could* be done to allow the function to be defined outside of `gml::tensor<T>::shape`.

Note: removing the `tensor` and `operator<<` forward declarations does not make any difference.

Comment: You `friend` a non-template function, yet your actual `operator<<` is a template. I'd move the definition of `operator<<` to the class body. Or you can `friend` the whole template. (Or declare the template beforehand and `friend` a specific specialization of it.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks a lot. When you say "`friend` the whole template", do you mean declaring `operator<<` as a templated friend function within `gml::tensor<T>::shape`? I've also tried specializing it, but to no avail. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you see any compiler warnings? Enable -Wall -Wextra at least.

Comment: *"friend the whole template"* - that would be `template <Numeric T> friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const typename tensor<T>::shape&);` inside of the class, I think.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks a lot, I had tried that previously, but it didn't work either. I'll just define the function within the class :( I much appreciate the help!